# Multiple amp-auto-ads on the same page

Tags: amp-html, amp-ad

I am trying to understand if multiple `amp-auto-ads` from different networks would work correctly if implemented simultaneously on the same page.

Currently I am facing the issue that `adConstraints` are not really kept. Here is example link, where both AdSense and FirstImpression.io are implemented, both networks have constraint of at least one viewport height distance between ads, but ads appear next to each other.

https://www.favecrafts.com/Knit-Baby-Blankets/Easy-Free-Knitting-Patterns-and-Help/amp#fi_reveal=113853 (preferably to look in mobile emulator)

Here how it looks like were the problem exists, ads are too close to each other:

[image: screenshot]

Anyone knows if this a config issue, or multiple `amp-auto-ads` are expeted to work like that?

***Additional info:***

AdConstriants from AdSense:

```
"adConstraints": {
  "initialMinSpacing":"1vp",
  "subsequentMinSpacing": [
    {"adCount":3,"spacing":"2vp"},
    {"adCount":6,"spacing":"3vp"}
  ],
  "maxAdCount":8
}
```

AdConstraints from FirstImpression.io:

```
"adConstraints": {
 "initialMinSpacing":"609px",
 "subsequentMinSpacing": [{"adCount":10,"spacing":"200px"}],
 "maxAdCount":100
}
```

Comment: should work; i have seen examples with different ad networks. while you didn't ask, it should be similal to a page supporting multiple analytic vendors.

Comment: @JayGray, right, it works in general, but the AdContraints thing does not seem to be kept. Any idea if that's a bug in the auto-ads extension?